# convert timedelta hh:mm to seconds

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I can't seem to find this anywhere but I'm trying to convert `timestamps` expressed as `hh:mm` to `total seconds`.

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['08:00','08:10','08:12','08:26','08:29','08:31','10:10','10:25','10:29','10:31'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If the timestamps were expressed as `hh:mm:ss` I would use the following:

```
secs = (pd.to_timedelta(df['A']).dt.total_seconds())
```

But when I try this on `hh:mm` I get an error?

`ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format`.

Is there a simple way to convert time when displayed as `hh:mm`

Comment: Is the problem the actual conversion to a timedelta object? or getting the total seconds from a timedelta object that was made with the format in your question?

Comment: The latter. Getting total seconds in the `hh:mm` format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append `:00` to the end of the string to convert it in the format `hh:mm:ss`.

Ex: `08:00` could be rewritten as `08:00:00`

Quick way to fix this:

```
d['A'] = [x + ':00' for x in d['A']]
```

And then, you can run the following:

```
secs = (pd.to_timedelta(d['A']).dt.total_seconds())
```

Comment: @Punter345 The end result is going to be the same.

Comment: @Punter345 So? Adding a 00 second component won't change the total_seconds result, will it?

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(df.A + ':00').dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: No, this is ok. I'll just append time to `hh:mm` later on. Just seems strange there's not a function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add seconds also in this way:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
         A
0  08:00:00
1  08:10:00
2  08:12:00
3  08:26:00
4  08:29:00
5  08:31:00
6  10:10:00
7  10:25:00
8  10:29:00
9  10:31:00
```

Answer (score 1):

if there is no 'senconds' value or you have hh:mm, then make it hh:mm:ss by simply adding string :00 to every value

```
d['A'] = d['A'] + ':00'
```

& then convert it to timedelta64 datatype

```
d['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(d['A'], unit='s')
```

Output

```
        A
0   08:00:00
1   08:10:00
2   08:12:00
3   08:26:00
4   08:29:00
5   08:31:00
6   10:10:00
7   10:25:00
8   10:29:00
9   10:31:00
```